# Pop3Client not authenticating for yahoo

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to retrieve mails from Yahoo account using vb.net. I have used openpopup (Pop3) to do that. Here is my code

```
Using client As New Pop3Client()<br/>
If client.Connected Then client.Disconnect()<br/>
clientConnect("pop.mail.yahoo.com", 995, true)<br/>
client.Authenticate("Yahoo UserName", "Yahoo Password",AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword)<br/>
client.Disconnect()<br/>
Return True<br/>
End Using<br/>
```

I stuck up with the following problem

`The server did not accept user credentials while authenticating it, but I am sure that the credentials are correct (I can connect the server with this credentials)`

I tried the same code with my gmail, hotmail and aol accounts. It works fine but not for Yahoo. When i try to authenticate with yahoo credentials, I got the following error.
"Server did not accept user credentials".

Please give me the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear you have Yahoo Plus or whatever they're calling it right?  You have to pay for pop access on yahoo.  If so are those the same settings that work in outlook or thunderbird?

Comment: Is any other mail server to read email from yahoo mail without made any payments?

Comment: Yahoo charges for pop access, that means accessing it from a program--not their website.  If you log in on web page there is no charge.  If you want to write your own program, or use outlook, or some other mail program, you need to have them allow access by IMAP or POP3, which they charge for.